# Magento 2 : How to set font icon using cdn url

Tags: magento2, less-css, cloudfront-cdn

In magento 2, How to set font icon using cdn url.

By default font icon comes from theme folder `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/web/css/source/_theme.less` file.

```
//  Fonts
@mobile-cart-padding : 10px;
@icons__font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Luma-Icons';
@icons__font-name: 'luma-icons';
```

How can we change **`baseDir`** with our cdn url to load icon in magento 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this yet in Magento 2 but I believe it should work:

```
@icons__font-path: url(**LINK-TO-FONT-URL**) format('**FORMAT-HERE**');
```

I used Google fonts as a reference of external fonts, you can see how they do it here - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans

Comment: what will set for LINK-TO-FONT-URL and my fonticon comes from app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/web/css/source folder and its not  directly call using url. any suggestion?

Comment: Your LINK-TO-FONT-URL will be the location of the font, for example https://yourcdn.com/fonts/fontname.woff. I declared the variable inside app/design/frontend/**STORE-NAME**/**THEME-NAME**/web/css/source/_theme.less